# Need to automatic "translate page" process or fix it. In google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, automation, translation

I am aware that question come up few times, but my problem is more specific.

In my job in necessary to spend 5-6 hours a day to do website search of various company around the globe. I need to automate this process, because clicking right click every time  on a every page to translate it manually take me good amount of my life time.

Chrome/google extension doesn't work properly, it doesn't translate automatically the page and i have no idea how to fix it.
Some keyboard shortcut would work but i dont know how to set it up.

- Keyboard shortcuts in extension menu is not enough
- I did try off and on option in chrome languages settings...

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has a [setting](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/173424?hl=en) the automatically translates all pages you visit in a specific language.

> To customize how translate will behave based on different languages
>   and pages you visit, click **Options** in the translate box that appears
>   under the icon.
>
> Select **Always translate** to automatically translate pages written in
>   the particular language selected.

[image]

Comment: I admit, somehow i missed this bubble. Nevertheless it's still doesnt work right. in 70% of cases page isn't translate. any idea what could help ?

Comment: It doesn't work. I don't think it ever has. You have to right click every single page even when you have told it to always translate a given language.